# Archive files without Sharepoint designer

Tags: 2013, document-archiving

What I have read it requires a workflow created in Sharepoint designer to automatically archive files. Can it be done in other ways?

Comment: Could you define automatic archiving?

Comment: This feels like a philosophical question. When an action takes place without the 
 need of a user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Information Management Policy** settings of library.

An information management policy is a set of rules for a type of content. Information management policies enable organizations to control and track things like how long content is retained or what actions users can take with that content. Information management policies can help organizations comply with legal or governmental regulations, or they can simply enforce internal business processes.

In your case, using Information management policy you can:

- Move document to recycle bin
- Permanently delete the document
- Transfer document to another location

For more information refer: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-information-management-policies-63a0b501-ba59-44b7-a35c-999f3be057b2

http://aspetraining.com/resources/blog/how-to-implement-information-management-policies-sharepoint-2013-%E2%80%93-part-2-of-2

Comment: I'd just add to the above answer by saying the policy can be applied to a single document library too, rather than content types.  (There are probably good reasons to apply policies to content types from a Sharepoint Architecture view - it depends how advanced your 'Sharepoint deployment' is.

Comment: I discovered that this only works on document libraries. Is there any way to do this on a task list?

Answer (score 4):

**Documents can be archived using two methods:**

- Manually archiving which is explained on this help page. You may need to [enable event functionality](https://www.filehold.com/help/system/enable-event-schedules-and-permissions) in Web Client > Administration Panel > System Configuration > General > Settings Permission Settings area. Enable the setting "Enable manually archiving documents" and, if needed, "Enable manually unarchiving documents"
- Using a [scheduled event to automatically archive documents](https://www.filehold.com/help/library/event-schedules).

Users with a Cabinet administrator role or higher can move electronic documents manually from the library into the library archive. Cabinet and Library administrators must be the owners of the cabinets in the library archive area in order to move documents in and out of the archive.

There are very limited operations that can be performed on archived documents. Documents that have been placed in the library archive section of the document management system can be:

- Left in the library archive indefinitely.
- Deleted from the library archive using an [Events Schedule](https://www.filehold.com/help/library/event-schedules).
- Moved back into the Library manually should the need arise.
- View or [get a copy](https://www.filehold.com/help/user/document-actions).
- Search using an [advanced search](https://www.filehold.com/help/user/advanced-searches)

When documents are sent to the library archive, the cabinet/drawer/folder group/folder structures is automatically duplicated. There is no need to recreate the structure. The security settings at the cabinet and folder levels are also maintained.

**To send a document, cabinet, drawer, folder group or folder into the library archive**

1. Do one of the following:

   - Right-click on a folder and select Archive Folder.
   - Right-click on one or more documents and select Send to > Library Archive.
2. The documents and/or folders are sent to the document Archive and the cabinet/drawer/folder group/folder structure is copied as well.

**To move archived items back to the library**

1. In the Library Archive, select the document or folder and select Copy or Move.
2. Select the Move files to a new location in the Library option and click Next.
3. Select the destination in the Library for the documents or folder and click OK.
4. At the alert message click OK. The documents and/or folder are moved back to the Library into their original location.

[Source](https://www.filehold.com/help/user/library-archive)